# ¿Cómo obtengo el valor de un select?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

estoy con una proyecto en JavaScript, HTML y CSS, y tengo un problema al capturar el valor de un select, para insertar en la base de datos y poder hacer un registro. Adjunto el código, y lo que he probado. He intentado varias cosas, pero al comprobar la base de datos no me guarda el valor que quiero (el atributo value de los option).

```
function mostrarRegistroAlumno(){
  var cadena='<div id="formRegistroAlumno" >';
  cadena=cadena+'<h3>Registro alumno </h3>';
  cadena=cadena+'<div class="form-group"><label for="nombre">Nombre: </label><input id="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"></div>';
  cadena=cadena+'<div class="form-group"><label for="apellidos">Apellidos: </label><input id="apellidos" type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos"></div>';
  cadena=cadena+'<div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-6"><label for="curso" class="control-label">Curso</label><select class="form-control" id="curso" name="curso">';
  cadena=cadena+'<option value="" selected="selected"></option><option value="1º">1º Primaria</option><option value="2º">2º Primaria</option><option value="3º">3º Primaria</option><option value="4º">4º Primaria</option><option value="5º">5º Primaria</option><option value="6º">6º Primaria</option></select></div>';
  cadena=cadena+'<div class="col-sm-6"><label for="edad">ATE: </label><div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="radioAte" value="No" checked>No</label></div>';
  cadena=cadena+'<div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="radioAte" value="Si">Si</label></div></div></div>';
  cadena=cadena+'<div class="form-group"><label for="contraseña">Contraseña: </label><input id="passwordA" type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordA" placeholder="Contraseña usuario"></div>';
  cadena=cadena+'<div class="form-group"><label for="rContraseña">Repetir contraseña: </label><input id="password2A" type="password" class="form-control" name="password2A" placeholder="Repita contraseña usuario"></div>';
  cadena=cadena+'<button type="button" id="registroBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Registrar Alumno</button>';
  cadena=cadena+'</div>';

  $('#registro').append(cadena);

  $('#registroBtn').on('click',function(){
    $('#formRegistroAlumno p').remove();

    var nombre=$('#nombre').val();
    var apellidos=$('#apellidos').val();
    // Esto he probado lo ultimo 
    $("#curso").change(function(){
      var curso = $(this).val();
    });

    var ate= $('input:radio[name=radioAte]:checked').val();
    var password=$('#passwordA').val();

    rest.registrarAlumno(password,curso,nombre,apellidos,ate);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas obteniendo el valor de la variable `curso` al momento de ocurrir el evento `change` y no al momento de pulsar el botón `registroBtn`, he modificado parte de tu codigo para tengas una idea de lo que debes hacer

```
$('#registroBtn').on('click',function(){
 $('#formRegistroAlumno p').remove();

 var nombre=$('#nombre').val(),
  apellidos=$('#apellidos').val();
  curso=$("#curso").val();

  var ate= $('input:radio[name=radioAte]:checked').val();
  var password=$('#passwordA').val();

  rest.registrarAlumno(password,curso,nombre,apellidos,ate);
});
```

Comment: Exacto, era así, pensaba que al tratarse de un select era necesario change.

Answer (score 2):

Veo varias cosas en tu código, unas extrañas y otras erróneas:

1. Es extraño que quieras construir el contenido HTML dentro de una función de Javascript ¿? ¿Por qué ese proceder cuando puedes escribir ese contenido directamente como HTML. (No he modificado nada en ese sentido porque no sé si tienes un motivo para hacerlo así). Pero debes saber que ese modo es costoso. Puedes tener el formulario fijo y actualizar sus elementos de forma dinámica si fuera preciso, así no tienes que recrear todo de nuevo.
2. Tienes los *listeners*  `$('#registroBtn').on('click',function(){` y `$("#curso").change(function(){` dentro de la función destinada a crear el contenido HTML. Eso es incorrecto. En caso de ser necesarios, esos *listeners*  deberían ir dentro del contexto del DOM, no dentro del contexto de la función `mostrarRegistroAlumno()`
3. Para obtener el valor de `curso` no tienes que usar un *listener* para ese `select`, lo obtienes directamente como haces con los `input`, es lo mismo en ese sentido. El *listener*  on change sería si quieres lanzar alguna acción cuando se cambie una opción en ese `select`, y si fuera el caso, debes ponerlo dentro de `function`, como hemos hecho con el *listener*  del botón.
4. El código que sigue funciona, recoge los datos correctamente como podrás ver en la consola. Ahora todo depende de lo que haga tu método `rest.registrarAlumno(password,curso,nombre,apellidos,ate);`

```js
$(function() {
  mostrarRegistroAlumno();

  $('#registroBtn').on('click', function() {
    var nombre = $('#nombre').val();
    var apellidos = $('#apellidos').val();
    var curso = $('#curso').val();
    var ate = $('input:radio[name=radioAte]:checked').val();
    var password = $('#passwordA').val();
    console.log(`password: ${password}, curso:${curso}, nombre:${nombre}, apellidos:${apellidos}, ate: ${ate}`);
    //rest.registrarAlumno(password,curso,nombre,apellidos,ate);
  });

});

function mostrarRegistroAlumno() {
  var cadena = '<div id="formRegistroAlumno" >';
  cadena = cadena + '<h3>Registro alumno </h3>';
  cadena = cadena + '<div class="form-group"><label for="nombre">Nombre: </label><input id="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"></div>';
  cadena = cadena + '<div class="form-group"><label for="apellidos">Apellidos: </label><input id="apellidos" type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos"></div>';
  cadena = cadena + '<div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-6"><label for="curso" class="control-label">Curso</label><select class="form-control" id="curso" name="curso">';
  cadena = cadena + '<option value="" selected="selected"></option><option value="1º">1º Primaria</option><option value="2º">2º Primaria</option><option value="3º">3º Primaria</option><option value="4º">4º Primaria</option><option value="5º">5º Primaria</option><option value="6º">6º Primaria</option></select></div>';
  cadena = cadena + '<div class="col-sm-6"><label for="edad">ATE: </label><div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="radioAte" value="No" checked>No</label></div>';
  cadena = cadena + '<div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="radioAte" value="Si">Si</label></div></div></div>';
  cadena = cadena + '<div class="form-group"><label for="contraseña">Contraseña: </label><input id="passwordA" type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordA" placeholder="Contraseña usuario"></div>';
  cadena = cadena + '<div class="form-group"><label for="rContraseña">Repetir contraseña: </label><input id="password2A" type="password" class="form-control" name="password2A" placeholder="Repita contraseña usuario"></div>';
  cadena = cadena + '<button type="button" id="registroBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Registrar Alumno</button>';
  cadena = cadena + '</div>';
  $('#registro').append(cadena);


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="registro"></div>
```

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por contestar. Respecto de los comentarios, en efecto la captura de datos del select se hace igual que los inputs. Y bueno, más que nada el HTML lo pongo dentro de JavaScript por comodidad a la hora de llamar a los eventos del cliente Rest y de WebSocket. Muchas gracias por la ayuda, saludos