# Problema con las comillas al pasar argumento

Tags: javascript, css, html5

estoy con el desarrollo de un proyecto en JavaScript, HTML y CSS, y me encuentro con un problema a la hora de pasar un argumento en un `onClick`. El código es el siguiente.

```
function mostrarTablaEjercicios(datos){

  var cadena ='<div id="tabla" class="container"><h2>Listado de ejercicios profesor</h2><p>Ejercicios presentes en la base de datos creados por ti</p>';
  cadena = cadena + '<table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr class="w3-red">';
  cadena = cadena + '<th>Nombre Ejercicio</th><th>ID Profesor</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Acciones</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
  for(var i=0;i<datos.length;i++){
    cadena = cadena + '<tr><td>'+datos[i].nombre+'</td><td>'+datos[i].uProfesor+'</td><td>'+datos[i]._id+'</td>';
    // Problema en este onclick
    cadena= cadena+ '<td><a href="#" id="papelera" onclick="rest.eliminarEjercicio('+datos[i]._id+');"><img id="papelera" src="cliente/img/trash-can.png" style="width:15%" ></a></td></tr>';
  }
  cadena = cadena + '</tbody></table>';
  cadena = cadena + '<button type="button" id="mostrarTodosBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Ver todos</button></div>';

  $('#tablas').append(cadena);

  $('#mostrarTodosBtn').on('click',function(){
    rest.obtenerEjercicios();
  });
}
```

La idea, es una tabla en la que en una de las columnas sea solo para acciones, es decir, eliminar un ejercicio, mostrar un ejercicio o editarlo. De momento solo he probar con eliminar el ejercicio `rest.eliminarEjercicio(idEjercicio)`, dicho id, lo tengo para cada ejercicio que muestro en la tabla en la variable `datos[i]._id`, sin embargo no sé como poner dicha variable para que sea aceptada como argumento.

Comment: Aparte de que estás poniendo el mismo ID a todos los elementos generados, no veo problemas en el código: ¿Qué error estás teniendo?

Comment: Evita llamar funciones *inline*, es una mala práctica. Es mejor usar eventos de Javascript, identificas el elemento por su id y le agregas un *listener*. Así el código HTML queda independiente del código Javascript, todo es más claro y más fácil de mantener. Es algo parecido a lo que haces con el botón: `$('#mostrarTodosBtn').on('click',function(){`  poniendolo así: `$('#papelera').on('click',function(){ //código ... }` es mucho más claro y más limpio que poner un `onClick` en el HTML.

Comment: Y [en la otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/252408/29967) te dije que estaba mal poner el listener del botón dentro de la función `mostrarTablaEjercicios()`... Es poner una función dentro de otra función. Tienes que abrir un ámbito general del DOM usando `function()` y poner allí todos los eventos de escucha de los elementos como `$('#mostrarTodosBtn').on('click',function(){ }` y todos los que tengan que ver con elementos del DOM. Si no lo haces así,  o tu código fallará. El ámbito de `function` sirve además para asegurar que no se use nada del DOM hasta que éste no está cargado.

Comment: Recuerda que el id debe ser un identificador unico y estas agregando id dentro de un ciclo, es decir, que puede haber varios lo que no es correcto `id="papelera"`

Comment: Buenas Pablo, el problema es a la hora de realizar el onClick, el error es de sintaxis, es un Invalid or unexpected token.

Comment: Buenas A. Cedano, eso que dices de la function y poner todos los eventos no lo conocía, lo hice así porque un profesor de la facultad me lo recomendó. Tal vez pruebe después como indicas. Respecto de `$('#papelera').on('click',function(){ //código ... }` no sé como puedo tener el atributo datos[i]._id que indico al estar fuera del for. No sé si me explico de forma adecuada

Comment: Es cierto denifer, probaré a cambiar el id, pero aún así no tengo claro como pasar el argumento `datos[i]._id`

Comment: puedes usar [string literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cómo bien te han dicho en los comentarios, es mejor que evites las funciones inline.

Para tu pregunta, puedes probar a quitar el método onclick y en su lugar usar los atributos data y agregarle una clase para poder interactuar con elemento:

```
cadena= cadena+ '<td><a href="#" id="papelera" class="ejemplo-papelera" data-datos-id="'+datos[i]._id+'"><img id="papelera" src="cliente/img/trash-can.png" style="width:15%" ></a></td></tr>';
```

Y luego recogerla así:

```
$('.ejemplo-papelera').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).data('datos-id');
    // resto del código necesario para eliminar el ejercicio...
);
```

Comment: Vale, he probado como indicas, añadiendo el código para eliminar el ejercicio `rest.eliminarEjercicio(id)`, sin embargo al probarlo el error que me sale es el siguiente: Uncaught TypeError: t.replace is not a function, en la línea donde se define la variable id.

Comment: He corregido el código, me faltaban unas comillas al recuperar el id

Comment: En efecto, así era. Muchas gracias por la ayuda. No conocía la forma con lo que has solucionado el problema. Una pregunta respecto a eso. Si necesito varios argumentos, podría hacer `data-datos-id="'+datos[i]._id+'"`,  `data-datos-nombre="'+datos[i].nombre+'"` y así sucesivamente?

Comment: Sí, puedes agregar los que quieras siempre que comiencen por ``data-``, aquí tienes unos cuantos ejemplos  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: Vale, les voy a echar un ojo. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque la solución que te han dado es mejor, también tienes la opción de las [string templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) para evitar problemas de comillas y concatenado de cadenas.

Envolviendo el texto entre tildes invertidas `` puedes poner el texto deseado, añadir saltos de línea directamente y hacer referencia a variables o funciones con `${}` (**ojo**, ese `$` no es el de `Jquery`, es un signo propio para esta utilidad)

```js
let dat=[{nombre: "nombre 1",uProfesor: "Profesor 1", _id: "1"},
{nombre: "nombre 2",uProfesor: "Profesor 2", _id: "2"},
{nombre: "nombre 3",uProfesor: "Profesor 3", _id: "3"},
{nombre: "nombre 4",uProfesor: "Profesor 4", _id: "4"},
{nombre: "nombre 5",uProfesor: "Profesor 5", _id: "5"},]

mostrarTablaEjercicios(dat);

function mostrarTablaEjercicios(){

let cadena= `<div id="tabla" class="container"><h2>Listado de ejercicios profesor</h2><p>Ejercicios presentes en la base de datos creados por ti</p>
<table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr class="w3-red">
<th>Nombre Ejercicio</th><th>ID Profesor</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Acciones</th></tr></thead><tbody>${htmlFor(dat)}
 </tbody></table>
  <button type="button" id="mostrarTodosBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Ver todos</button></div>`;

  $('#tablas').append(cadena);
}

function htmlFor(datos){
let cadenaAux = "";
for(var i=0;i<datos.length;i++){
   cadenaAux += `<tr><td>"${datos[i].nombre}"</td><td>${datos[i].uProfesor}</td><td>${datos[i]._id}</td>
    <td><a href="#" id="papelera" onclick="eliminarEjercicio(${datos[i]._id});"><img id="papelera" src="cliente/img/trash-can.png" style="width:15%" ></a></td></tr>`
  }
  return cadenaAux;
}

function eliminarEjercicio(id){
  console.log(`Vas a eliminar el ejercicio ${id}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tablas"></div>
```